# Two way binding in ng-click

Tags: angular

I have a component with an Input of action with name, icon and function, and I need the function launch when click in the component.

Here is the call to component

```
<div *ngFor="let action of searchedQuestionnaire.actions;">
  <option-button [action]="action"></option-button>
</div>
```

Here the component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-main-color margin-left-5" (click)="action.function">
  <i [class]="'fa ' + action.icon + ' fa-lg'"></i> {{ action.name | translate}}
</button>
```

Here the component.ts

```
export class OptionButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() action;

  constructor() {
  }

  editQuestionnaire() {
    console.log('editQuestionnaire')
  }

  createQuestionnaire() {
    console.log('createQuestionnaire')
  }

  deleteQuestionnaire() {
    console.log('deleteQuestionnaire')
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And this is the array of actions

```
    "actions": [
      {
        "name": "EDIT",
        "icon": "fa-pencil",
        "function": "editQuestionnaire",
      },
      {
        "name": "DELETE",
        "icon": "fa-trash",
        "function": "deleteQuestionnaire",
      },
      {
        "name": "COPY",
        "icon": "fa-files-o",
        "function": "copyQuestionnaire",
      }
    ]
```

(I also try passing () at finish the function)

I suppouse I need to have a click with two binding way (bananas in a box [(click)] because I need read the function from action.function, but execute the one in the ts, but I have an error:

> Can't bind to 'click' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
export class OptionButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() btnName: string;
  @Input() icon: string;
  @Output() onOptionBtnClick() = new EventEmitter<void>();

}
```

and in it's template it would look sthg like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-main-color margin-left-5" (click)="action.function">
  <i [class]="'fa ' + action.icon + ' fa-lg'"></i> {{ action.name | translate}}
</button>
```

Then you can bind in the parent template to the `onOptionsBtnClick` event by

```
<option-button
  [name]="action.name"
  [icon]=action.icon
  (onOptionsBtnClick)="action.function()"
></option-button>
```

... in my humble opionion it would be a lot cleaner if you don't need to build such a complex "action"-object/"action"-array and simply code the 3 buttons that look sthg like:

```
<option-button
  btnName="EDIT"
  icon="firstIcon"
  (onOptionsBtnClick)="editQuestionnaire()"
></option-button>

<option-button
  btnName="DELETE"
  icon="fa-trash"
  (onOptionsBtnClick)="deleteQuestionnaire()"
></option-button>

<option-button
  btnName="COPY"
  icon="fa-files-o"
  (onOptionsBtnClick)="copyQuestionnaire()"
></option-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. I entered this problem a while back with the goal of creating one versatile action component. This one component would take a configuration object loaded with ActionButton's not unlike your "actions" object you have above among other configuration type parameters.

see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-buttons)